# MPI on a single machine dualcore

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi

What happend if I ran an MPI program which require 3 nodes (i.e. mpiexec -np 3 ./Program) on a single machine which has 2 cpu?

Comment: May I suggest the removal of "concurrency" as a tag? MPI gives you parallel execution, but no concurrency in the sense that you can write a web server, say with it.

Answer (score 11):

This depends on your MPI implementation, of course. Most likely, it will create three processes, and use shared memory to exchange the messages. This will work just fine: the operating system will dispatch the two CPUs across the three processes, and always execute one of the ready processes. If a process waits to receive a message, it will block, and the operating system will schedule one of the other two processes to run - one of which will be the one that is sending the message.

Comment: But say I want the three processes to be as independent as possible, and communicate only via message passing. Ideally then I would need a machine with 3 cpus, right? As an MPI implementation I am using MPICH2.

Comment: Wrong. The processes will be independent already on two processors. The operating system will just schedule them; each one will get 66% of one CPU. Unless they block waiting for messages, they will run "full speed" (meaning they will keep both CPUs under full load, and make all individual progress).

Comment: The assumption that the OS will deschedule the process on a blocking send/recv operation is not universally true.  Some MPI implementations behave this way and some do not, usually for performance reasons.  For example, the stock build of the current MPICH2 release will _not_ block (in the OS sense) on a blocking MPI operation.

Answer (score 10):

Martin has given the right answer and I've plus-1ed him, but I just want to add a few subtleties which are a little too long to fit into the comment box.

There's nothing wrong with having more processes than cores, of course; you probably have dozens running on your machine well before you run any MPI program.   You can try with any command-line executable you have sitting around something like `mpirun -np 24 hostname` or `mpirun -np 17 ls` on a linux box, and you'll get 24 copies of your hostname, or 17 (probably interleaved) directory listings, and everything runs fine.

In MPI, this using more processes than cores is generally called 'oversubscribing'.  The fact that it has a special name already suggests that its a special case.   The sorts of programs written with MPI typically perform best when each process has its own core.  There are situations where this need not be the case, but it's (by far) the usual one.   And for this reason, for instance, OpenMPI has optimized for the usual case -- it just makes the strong assumption that every process has its own core, and so is very agressive in using the CPU to poll to see if a message has come in yet (since it figures it's not doing anything else crucial).  That's not a problem, and can easily be turned off if OpenMPI knows it's being oversubscribed ( http://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=running#oversubscribing ).    It's a design decision, and one which improves the performance of the vast majority of cases.

For historical reasons I'm more familiar with OpenMPI than MPICH2, but my understanding is that MPICH2s defaults are more forgiving of the oversubscribed case -- but I think even there, too it's possible to turn on more agressive busywaiting.

Anyway, this is a long way of saying that yes, there what you're doing is perfectly fine, and if you see any weird problems when you switch MPIs or even versions of MPIs, do a quick search to see if there are any parameters that need to be tweaked for this case.

Comment: Thank you guys. This clarifies my doubts.

Comment: The default channel in MPICH2 (ch3:nemesis) does not support oversubscription very well at the moment, although better support is a planned feature for the future.  If you configure MPICH2 with ch3:sock instead then oversubscription shouldn't be a problem, but shared memory won't be used for communication within the node.  Relevant FAQ entry: http://wiki.mcs.anl.gov/mpich2/index.php/Frequently_Asked_Questions#Q:_Why_does_my_MPI_program_run_much_slower_when_I_use_more_processes.3F